# Transit in Johannesburg

Tags: transit, emirates, jnb

I will be flying on SA Airlink flight from Swaziland to Johannesburg and on Emirates from Johannesburg to Pakistan. Transit time at O.R. Tambo is 4 hours. I want to know if Airline will transfer my luggage on connecting flight from Johannesburg to Pakistan. How will I get my boarding pass from Johannesburg to Pakistan in the transit area?

Comment: Normally when on two separate tickets you have to retrieve and recheck your luggage, but if the airlines have an interlining agreement you might be able to get them to check the bags through. If you're on a single ticket then in most cases yes, they wll transfer the luggage. Some countries require you to retrieve and recheck the luggage anyway; I'm not sure about South Africa. If your luggage is checked through and you're unable to get a boarding pass in Swaziland, you can get one in the transit area, either from a transfer desk (if there is one) or from the gate agent at your departure gate.

Answer (score 4):

SA Airlink can check baggage through to Dubai on Emirates. This of course means that it would be able to be checked all the way through to Pakistan as well. Just make sure when you check in at the Airlink counter that you inform the agent that you are connecting to an Emirates flight and provide them with your onward connection details.

You can pick up a boarding pass at a transfer desk, if they don't give you one in Swaziland.